# Selecting from pandas groups without replacement when possible

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have a Dataframe that looks like:

```
Name Group_Id
A    1
B    2
C    2
```

I want a piece of code that selects n sets such that, as much as possible would contain different members of the same group.
A representative from each group must appear in each set (the representatives should be picked at random).
Only if the group's size is smaller than n, the same representatives would appear in multiple sets.
n is smaller or equal to the size of the biggest group.
So for example, for the above Dataframe and n=2 this would be a valid result:

```
set 1 
Name Group_Id
A    1
B    2

set 2 
Name Group_Id
A    1
C    2
```

however this one is not

```
set 1 
Name Group_Id
A    1
B    2

set 2 
Name Group_Id
A    1
B    2
```

Comment: groupby sample ?

Comment: would that ensure I get different members when possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) with replacement each group which has a smaller size than that of the largest group, such that each dataframe will have a sample from each group. Then interleave the inner groups' rows, and build a list of dataframes as shared:

```
# size of largest group
max_size = df.groupby('Group_Id').size().max()
# upsample group if necessary
l = [g.sample(max_size, replace=True) if g.shape[0]<max_size else g 
     for _,g in df.groupby('Group_Id')]
# interleave rows and build list of dataframes
[pd.DataFrame(g, columns=df.columns) for g in zip(*(i.to_numpy().tolist() for i in l))]
[  Name  Group_Id
 0    A         1
 1    B         2,
   Name  Group_Id
 0    A         1
 1    C         2]
```

Comment: Nice one, maybe you can just sample the index.

Comment: Thanks @quang Guess I'd still have to redefine those dataframes, would possibly make it easier though

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea:

```
# 1. label a random order within each Group_Id
df['sets'] = df.sample(frac=1).groupby('Group_Id').cumcount()

# 2. pivot the table and using ffill
sets = (df.pivot(index='sets',columns='Group_Id').ffill() # for groups with fewer than N elements, choose the last elements always
   .stack('Group_Id').reset_index('Group_Id')             # return Group_Id as a normal column
)

# slices:
N = 2
for i in range(N):
    print(sets.loc[i])
```

Output:

```
      Group_Id Name
sets               
0            1    A
0            2    C
      Group_Id Name
sets               
1            1    A
1            2    B
```